# Is there a dockerpty similar alternative with podman?

Tags: python, docker, podman

Docker PTY
Provides the functionality needed to operate the pseudo-tty (PTY) allocated to
a docker container, using the Python client.
ref: https://pypi.org/project/dockerpty/

I'm looking for similar to use with PodmanClient in python.
If you know any other way to doing same thing in podman and python client. Please mention it.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, there is an Open Python client for [Podman](https://github.com/containers/podman) named [podman-py](https://github.com/containers/podman-py)  ✅

**Note:** [podman-py](https://github.com/containers/podman-py) is not fully matured but it is the **right** place to start.

Another alternative is [python3-podman](https://github.com/containers/python-podman) but this project is been archived ref [python-support-for-podman.html](https://podman.io/blogs/2018/08/15/python-support-for-podman.html)

https://github.com/containers/podman-py